# How to override an event handler that is not marked as virtual?

Tags: c#, event-handling, overriding, filesystemwatcher

I have to create a class that inherit from `FileSystemWatcher`. I should Intercept the event `OnCreated` and create my own event `OnCreated`. I have tried as follow:

```
public class LocalFolderWatcher : FileSystemWatcher, IWatcher
{
    ...
    public event LocalFolderEventHandler Created;

    protected override void OnCreated(FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath);
        LocalFolderEventArgs args = new LocalFolderEventArgs(e.ChangeType, this._gatewayConfigurationName, path, this._folderConfigurationName, e.Name);

        if (Created != null && base.EnableRaisingEvents && base.Path != null)
            Created(this, args);

        base.OnCreated(e);
    }
}
```

But I obtain an error: I cannot override a method that is not marked as virtual, abstract or override. I've tried to replace "override" with "new" but in this way the event is never raised..

How can I intercept the real "OnCreated" and replace with mine?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to replace `OnCreated`, just create your own handler and pass it to the `Created` event.

```
public class LocalFolderWatcher : FileSystemWatcher, IWatcher
{
    //...
    public event LocalFolderEventHandler CustomCreated;

    public LocalFolderWatcher()
    {
        Created += OnCreated;
    }

    private new void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath);
        LocalFolderEventArgs args = new LocalFolderEventArgs(e.ChangeType, this._gatewayConfigurationName, path, this._folderConfigurationName, e.Name);

        if (CustomCreated != null && base.EnableRaisingEvents && base.Path != null)
            CustomCreated(this, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to have just one event "created".. In this way I have to create an handler for CustomeCreated. :( however, if there is no other solution, iz ok... thank you

Comment: Sure, you can also change it to `public new event LocalFolderEventHandler Created;` and then `base.Created += OnCreated;`. Then change every `CustomCreated` to `Created`.

Comment: hi @IllidanS4wantsMonicaback with all due respect can you please check this question too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64238735/to-prevent-entering-special-characters-on-textbox-already-have-thousand-of-tex

Comment: @Banjo I believe that question is already sufficiently answered.

Comment: @IllidanS4supportsMonica Nope friend no bodies answer it correctly. What I need is to override current keypress event of the textbox and run my validation code plus need to run if there is any explicitly mentioned code inside key press events.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

If you're trying to *modify* what the default handler does, forget it, you can't. If you want to *add* your own behaviour, then you can just create a new handler and subscribe the event.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have the scenario

```
class BaseClass { public void M() { Console.WriteLine("BaseClass"); } }
class SubClass { public new void M() { Console.WriteLine("SubClass"); } }

void Main() {
    var x = new SubClass();
    x.M(); // Prints "SubClass"
    ((BaseClass)x).M(); // Prints "BaseClass"
}
```

In the first case, it calls `SubClass.M` and in the second it calls `BaseClass.M`. This is what "new" means - it creates a new method.

However, if we made `BaseClass.M` virtual and marked `SubClass.M` as override, then both of them would print "SubClass", because virtual calls check the *runtime* type of the caller. This explains why your event is never raised.

As IllidanS4 recommends, the best way is to add a listener to `FileSystemWatcher.Created` and make it call `LocalFolderWatcher`.

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to the OnCreated event in FileSystemWatcher and then call your own method