# To prevent entering special characters on textbox ( Already have thousand of textboxes in solution )

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, special-characters

We have a advanced software written by using c# ( windows forms ). In their we have 1000 or more textboxes. I need to validate user input on all these textboxes to stop entering special characters and any scripts. Textboxes are hard coded.

for eg :
I can use following piece of code on every keypress to check whether user has entered the allowed characters or not.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]");
    if (regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString()))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

but then we have to implement this on every textboxes key press events ( if there is no other solution this is the last thing to do). Is there any way to handle this from a single place and affect for every textboxes (on some places textboxes have their own key press events as well). What I need is a common method which will be fire on every key press events of any textbox.

Solution : Create a Custom Control derived from TextBox (or TextBoxBase) that contains all the logic required for my validation, so it's all done in one place.
But still I have to again change all the existing textboxes my new textbox.
Is there any way to change behavior of current event handler?

**Note: What I need is to override current keypress event of the textbox and run my validation code plus need to run if there is any explicitly mentioned code inside key press events.**

Comment: Are you generating the textboxes dynamically or are they hard coded?

Comment: @MathewHD Textboxes are hard coded

Comment: Why don't you build a Custom Control derived from TextBox that contains all the logic required by your validation, so it's all done in one place? No need for event handlers, all validation code in a single package...

Comment: @Jimi Thanks Jimi,
But still I have to again change all the existing textboxes to my new textbox.
Is there any way to change behavior of current event handler?

Comment: Yes, of course: `CTRL+H` and replace all `new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()` occurrences with, say, `new MySpecialTextBox()` (whatever name you have assigned to the Custom class object). - Make a test in a dummy Project to get acquainted, of course -

Comment: Btw, in a Custom Control, don't subscribe to the `KeyPress` event, override `OnKeyPress` instead.

Comment: Or a recursive function to get all the text boxes and subscribe to the same `KeyPress` handler?

Comment: Don't create the `Regex` object every time you press a key. Either store it in a variable, or use the static methods on the `Regex` class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the `KeyDown` Event to all `TextBoxes` you can loop through them and add the same `EventHandler` for all of them.

To do that first of all we need to create a function that loop through all our TextBoxes.

**GetChildControls Function:**

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TControl> GetChildControls<TControl>(this Control control) 
    where TControl : Control
{
    var children = (control.Controls != null) ? 
        control.Controls.OfType<TControl>() : Enumerable.Empty<TControl>();
    return children.SelectMany(c => GetChildControls<TControl>(c)).Concat(children);
}
```

We can now use that function after the `InitializeComponent();` to assign the `Txt_KeyDown()` EventHandler to all TextBoxes.

**Calling the Function:**

```cs
public Example() {
    InitializeComponent();
    var allTextBoxes = this.GetChildControls<TextBox>();
    foreach (TextBox tb in allTextBoxes)
    {
        tb.KeyDown += Txt_KeyDown;
    }
}

private void Txt_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about this pseudo-recursive method? It looks like you're searching for child controls of type `TControl` in their `Controls` collection. So, you'll return only direct `TControl` children of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

> "Is there any way to handle this from a single place and affect for
> every textboxes"

There's a few ways. But it seems you don't want to edit the textbox itself, so there's only one reliable way I'm aware of; attaching a global keyboard hook. Code follows:

```
class GlobalKeyboardHook
        {
            #region DLL Imports
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int hookEventId, keyboardProc callback, IntPtr handleInstance, uint threadId);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr handleInstance);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr ignoredParameter, int hookCode, int wParam, ref KeyboardHookStruct lParam);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string libFileName);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
            #endregion DLL Imports

            #region Class Declarations
            private delegate int keyboardProc(int code, int wParam, ref KeyboardHookStruct lParam);
            private keyboardProc kbdProc;

            public struct KeyboardHookStruct
            {
                public int vkCode;
                public int scanCode;
                public int flags;
                public int time;
                public int extraInfo;
            }

            private static class KeyboardMessages
            {
                public const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
                public const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
                public const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
                public const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
                public const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;
            }
            
            IntPtr HookPointer = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr ModuleInstance = IntPtr.Zero;

            public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
            public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;

            #endregion Class Declarations

            #region Class Functions
            public GlobalKeyboardHook() {
                EnableHook(true, null);
            }

            public GlobalKeyboardHook(Process P) {
                EnableHook(true, P);
            }

            ~GlobalKeyboardHook() {
                EnableHook(false, null);
            }

            public void EnableHook(bool Enabled)
            {
                EnableHook(Enabled, null);
            }

            public void EnableHook(bool Enabled, Process P) {
                if (Enabled)
                {
                    HookPointer = SetWindowsHookEx(KeyboardMessages.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, kbdProc = HookCallback, ModuleInstance = P == null ? LoadLibrary("User32") : GetModuleHandle(P.MainModule.ModuleName), 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    UnhookWindowsHookEx(HookPointer);
                    HookPointer = IntPtr.Zero;
                    ModuleInstance = IntPtr.Zero;
                    kbdProc = null;
                }  
            }

            public int HookCallback(int code, int wParam, ref KeyboardHookStruct lParam) {
                if (code >= 0) {    
                    KeyEventArgs key = new KeyEventArgs((Keys)lParam.vkCode);
                    if ((wParam == KeyboardMessages.WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == KeyboardMessages.WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (KeyDown != null)) {
                        KeyDown(this, key) ;
                    } else if ((wParam == KeyboardMessages.WM_KEYUP || wParam == KeyboardMessages.WM_SYSKEYUP) && (KeyUp != null)) {
                        KeyUp(this, key);
                    }
                    if (key.Handled)
                        return 1;
                }
                return CallNextHookEx(HookPointer, code, wParam, ref lParam);
            }
            #endregion Class Functions
        }
```

To activate we add the following:

```
GlobalKeyboardHook ghk = new GlobalKeyboardHook(Process.GetCurrentProcess());
Type tbType = typeof(TextBox);
ghk.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(() => {
    if (typeof(this.ActiveControl) == tbType)
        RunValidation(this.ActiveControl.Text);
});
```

Once you have the boilerplate hook, adding validation becomes pretty simple. No loops means you're not wasting processor time iterating over a thousand text boxes.

Just remember this will apply to ALL controls of type TextBox within the current process. If you add a custom TextBox control or don't want to check all of them - that should be accounted for prior to calling RunValidation().